# 12.04 making BCM4313 card work with aircrack-ng?

Tags: 12.04, broadcom, aircrack-ng

I'm a real Linux Noob, just started using it (this month) and until now i had no issues.

now i'm trying to set-up aircrack-ng on my laptop, but it seems like it's using the worst card possible (or almost)

there is a TON of tutorial on this card (seems to be hell to set-up)

i have tryed some, but i ended up uninstalling my drivers, messing with my desktops, and ended by having no more "X" to close my windows (i have no clue how i ended there)

i just re-installed my linux (took me 2 hours to setup everything again), but now i'm a bit "Scared" to try tutorials randomly again.

---

Right now it says the driver is wl, wich is not the one i want (AFAIK it's not supported)

---

i'm not sure what kind of informations are needed, but here's what i think could be usefull.

lspci -knn

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel driver in use: mei
    Kernel modules: mei
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] [10de:0df4] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidiafb
```

WIRELESS CARD

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Wistron NeWeb Corp. Device [185f:051a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, bcma, brcmsmac
```

REST...

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0a5]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

---

Also, if i'm "screwed" with my hardware, just tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension on t3ch's *answer*. Edit  `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`  and change eth* to wlan0.